# Why are x and y switched here?

Tags: proj, pyproj

I'm trying to convert between EPSG:7665 and EPSG:32145, but I have to swap the x and y values to get the correct answer.

From this datasheet [reference point](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/ds_mark.prl?PidBox=OD1097), here's the position:

```
OD1097* NAD 83(2011) POSITION- 43 39 51.48273(N) 072 18 45.97541(W)   ADJUSTED
```

... and the converted result should be:

```
OD1097;                    North         East     Units Scale Factor Converg. 
OD1097;SPC VT       -   129,359.640   515,100.803   MT 0.99996709   +0 07 45.4
```

But, from a Python prompt, I'm seeing this:

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> t = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(7665, 32145)
>>> 
>>> # incorrect
>>> t.transform(xx=-72.31277095, yy=43.66430076)
(2289759.92653163, -15602309.175105048)
>>> 
>>> # correct
>>> t.transform(yy=-72.31277095, xx=43.66430076)
(515100.8023760433, 129359.6397831659)
```

The [pyproj documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.transform) has:

> xx (scalar or array) – Input x coordinate(s).
>
> yy (scalar or array) – Input y coordinate(s).

Why is swapping the x and y values giving me the correct answer? Or is something else going on here?

Comment: It is all about the meaning of x and y, or rather, the first and second coordinate. For EPSG:7665 the order is `Axes: latitude, longitude, ellipsoidal height. Orientations: north, east, up.` https://epsg.org/crs_7665/WGS-84-G1762.html.

Comment: @user30184 So xx represents latitude here when using EPSG:7665?

Comment: Yes. See the warning and the hint in the beginning of the documentation https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.transform "The axis order may be swapped if the source and destination CRS’s are defined as having the first coordinate component point in a northerly direction (See PROJ FAQ on axis order). You can check the axis order with the pyproj.crs.CRS class. If you prefer to keep your axis order as always x,y, you can use the always_xy option when creating the pyproj.transformer.Transformer."

Comment: @user30184 Thank you, if you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your question is a duplicate of some of these https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=pyproj+axis+order